# MSQL DDL from JDL - Jhipster

Tags: java, mysql, jhipster, jdl

Hi Have started working with JHipster recently. Wanted to know if there is way with which JDL can be converted to DDL to be exported to MySQL database. Seems a newbie question but did not get much answers on google. Or is it that when we configure local MySQL using application-dev.yml what every entity changes we do gets propagated to the MySQL, not completely sure here please help me out with this.

Comment: JHipster uses Liquibase not DDL

Answer (score 0):

> Wanted to know if there is way with which JDL can be converted to DDL to be exported to MySQL database

Generate codes then run project so your tables will create and you can get ddl.

> Or is it that when we configure local MySQL using application-dev.yml what every entity changes we do gets propagated to the MySQL

This is what exacly liquibase do for us. It will managing and applying database schema changes. For more information visit [here](https://www.liquibase.org/)